# how to display the selected image with a button

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to get the selected img and display it when i click the "save" button, but the answers online shows how to display it when selected.

1. Select an img from "choose File" `<input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="image" id="file">`.

2.After selected when i click "Save" `<button type="button" onclick="loadFile(event)">Save</button>`.

i want it to be displayed in `<img id="img" width="200" />`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
.file{
width: 90px;
height: 100px;
}
</style>
  <body>
    <input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="image" id="file"><label for="price">Kodi:</label>
    <input type="label" class="price" name="price">
    <label for="desc">Shtesë:</label>
    <input type="text" class="desc" name="desc"><button type="button" onclick="loadFile(event)">Save</button></br></br></br>
    </br></br></br>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th width="100px" border="2">image</th>
        <th width="200px;">Person</th>
        <th width="100px">age</th>
      </tr>
    </table></br>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th><img id="img" width="200" /></th>
        <th id="person" width="200px">Person</th>
        <th width="100px;">Age</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("desc").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("price").style.display = "none";
    function save(){
        document.getElementById('img').src = "IMG_0979.jpg";
        document.getElementById("price").innerText = "10$";
        document.getElementById("desc").innerText = "perde";
        document.getElementById("desc").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("price").style.display = "inline";

    }
var loadFile = function(event) {
  var image = document.getElementById('img');
  image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, here are the few errors I've noted…

1. since you're using `document.getElementById("desc").style…` an element must have an id equal to `desc`. Where you have  `<input type="text" class="desc" name="desc">` replace `class=` by `id=`.
2. Same for `document.getElementById("price").style…`
3. The loadFile function is called on a `click` event so `event.target.files[0]` is undefined. `event.target.files[0]` is only defined when listening change event on `<input type="file" …>`. You need to use a variable store `event.target.files[0]` once the change event has been fired and use this variable in your loadFile function.

Here is your code with the above corrections:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
.file{
width: 90px;
height: 100px;
}
</style>
  <body>
    <input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="image" id="file" onchange="fileChange(event)"><label for="price">Kodi:</label>
    <input type="label" id="price" name="price">
    <label for="desc">Shtesë:</label>
    <input type="text" id="desc" name="desc"><button type="button" onclick="loadFile(event)">Save</button></br></br></br>
    </br></br></br>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th width="100px" border="2">image</th>
        <th width="200px;">Person</th>
        <th width="100px">age</th>
      </tr>
    </table></br>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th><img id="img" width="200" /></th>
        <th id="person" width="200px">Person</th>
        <th width="100px;">Age</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("desc").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("price").style.display = "none";
    function save(){
        document.getElementById('img').src = "IMG_0979.jpg";
        document.getElementById("price").innerText = "10$";
        document.getElementById("desc").innerText = "perde";
        document.getElementById("desc").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("price").style.display = "inline";

    }
  
  var imgUrl;
  
  function fileChange(event) {
    imgUrl = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  }
var loadFile = function(event) {
  var image = document.getElementById('img');
  image.src = imgUrl;
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, i saw there was some errors but i did not fix. but what i need is when i click save i want the img to appear

Comment: Noted, i marked the answer, quick question is it posible to store the data that i put in with the save button as local up to 100tables or so

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, is it related to the code above ? Anyway you can store what ever you want. If you want to store many values under the same variable use an array or an object

Comment: yes this code, for ex. I choose an img and write something in the `<input>`s and click save and the data with the img to be stored in the table below

Comment: Do you want to create a row for every entry ?

Comment: Every data from a row of your table would be an object. Every object should be push in an array

Comment: whats the difference between the table in object and non-object,

Comment: nvr mind i understand why, now i just have to learn to make one cell img type and to change there data. :)